# File upload using cordova app not working on remote server

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, file-transfer

I am trying to upload a file using my cordova app. The file was uploaded successfully when i was testing with localhost url. Now when i am trying with my remote server, it gives me the following error. It looks like its not even hitting the upload-url

```
FileTransferError {code: 1, source: "file:///storage/emulated/0/rec_13_13_11.wav", target: "https:///mobile_api/upload-hla-call-recording", http_status: 500, body: null, …}
body:null
code:1
exception:"https://route/to/upload/file"
http_status:500
source:"file:///storage/emulated/0/rec_13_13_11.wav"
target:"https://route/to/upload/file"
```

Here is the code for uploading file

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory(dirName, {

                create: false

            }, function (dataDir) {

                fileURI = dataDir.toURL();

                fileURI = fileURI + fileName;

                var options = new FileUploadOptions();

                options.fileKey = "fileKey";

                options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                options.mimeType = "audio/mp3";

                options.chunkedMode = false;

                var ft = new FileTransfer();

                ft.upload(fileURI, server-url, win, fail, options, true);

            }, dirFail);
```

I am using cordova-plugin-file-transfer to upload the file

Comment: `HTTP Status Code` `500` simply means there's something wrong in your `PHP` code.

Comment: yes but the same code works fine on my localhost, the file is properly getting uploaded. It shows this error for remote server

Comment: Well, with information this little, I can't help much. Provide more info if you can.

Comment: i have added the code for reference @AmitMerchant

Comment: And the path `<domain>/route/to/upload/file` really exists on your Server? I mean in document root of your web app? Did you check write permissions of your webserver?

Comment: Yes, the permissions are exactly same as my local server. Also when I add the header Content-Type: audio/mp3, the request goes in backend but it fails to send the data, so all i get is NULL in backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was regarding the guzzlehttp. It was looking for https connection while my localhost was working on http. Either force the curl for http or provide a certificate with your http request.